# Angular web build deploy shows white screen when I refresh the page

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have made Angular web build successfully , I deploy successfully on live server , change the path base_href path in index.html,and it works fine .

Now the issue is when I refresh the page it appears white screen why ?

How to resolve it ?

Can anyone help me to overcome from this solution ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We will need further information to help you. Any console errors? Any failed network requests?

Comment: Sorry It just loads white screen , no console error occures

Comment: And in the network tab, can you see that your static application files have loaded as expected (HTML, CSS, JS)?

Comment: I think it's the delay while loading all your modules from live server. Try lazy loading modules, keep the app module light weight which will solve the issue. At least I'm pretty sure it won't appear in production bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to insert a wb.config file and configure routing to in your angular app so that on build it will depending on the server you have to specify web.config or you have to use other strategies. Follow the link for using other strategies.

http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: I review your links but still it is not working , My server is azure linux server , and I uploading my local build after setup angular + NativeScript.